# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message

this is the error message given in rails server: `<%  @toy_all.each do |m| %>`

what's wrong with this line and how can i change it?

this is the coding in controller

```
class SalreportController < ApplicationController
  def salout
  @employee_count = Employee.count
  @employee_all = Employee.all

  end
end
```

Comment: Please edit to add the error message, you've posted a snippet of view code, which does not directly overlap (in variable names at least) with the code from the controller action you posted

Answer (score 1):

You don't have @toy_all defined (only @employee_all), so you should add `@toy_all = Toys.all` in your controller (naming it @toys would be more common).

Off topic, you query the db twice with your code, instead do:

```
@employees = Employee.all
@employee_count = @employees.length
```

Comment: the beginning of my toys controller is: class ToysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_toy, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /toys
  # GET /toys.json
  def index
    @toys = Toy.all
  end

  # GET /toys/1
  # GET /toys/1.json
  def show
  end

Comment: If `<% @toy_all.each do |m| %>` is rendered from a SalreportController  view, you'll have to declare @toys again in that controller (else it gives an undefined/nil error).

Comment: I realized what the problem was it was in another file toy.rb. now i'm getting the error message about strong parameters. I think it's just that rails 4 doesn't use attributes anymore. the code for my toy.rb is: class Toy < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible  :name, :price, :vendor
 validates  :name, :presence => true
 validates  :price, :presence => true
 validates  :price, :numericality => true
 validates  :vendor, :presence => true 
end
how can I change this to strong parameters?

Comment: That's with `params.permit(:name, :price, :etc)` in your controller, you can also use the `protected_attributes` gem until you've done further research on strong parameters.

Comment: I changed it and it gave me the message "undefined local variable or method `params'" I changed it to:                                      class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 params.permit(:name, :price, :salary, :ssn)                              validates  :first, :presence => true
 validates  :last, :presence => true
 validates  :salary, :presence => true
 validates  :salary, :numericality => true
 validates  :ssn, :presence => true 
end

Comment: You need to change the params.permit line from your model to your controller, see also: [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). And please mark this as answer since it resolved your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @toy.each do |m| %>
```

you don't need "all."

Also, make sure the variable toy is defined in your code.